# Navigate between TabViewController and NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have an View Controller(A) that is embedded in a Navigation Controller, and from which I'm doing a modal segue to another View Controller (B) which is inside another Tab View Controller, my question is how can I navigate from B back to A, I created a modal segue from B to the navigation controller in which is A and i perform that segue but I'm getting "Receiver A has no segue with identifier 'mySegue'", if I do a segue directly to A then I don't have the navigation controller displayed in the view anymore, i guess is due to the fact that is never initialized.

[image]

Can please someone point me to a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question syntax makes me think of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_mDTLphIVY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a segue to the previous viewController which may or may not be on the navigation stack, you don't go back to that controller, but instead create a new instance of the controller that will be pushed on the stack, creating a loop that will just use way too much memory. In this case, your stack would have `ABA` controllers, instead just `A`, if the segue worked.

What you really need is to go back in the navigation stack, depending on how exactly you added the controller to the stack. Because you used a modal segue, that means that your A controller also has to dismiss the B controller by using [dismissViewControllerAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:), which will show the A controller once again.

I suggest you look into [protocols and delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) to pass the message back to A once B has finished to dismiss it.

Comment: so basically I should dismiss the view controller B, after I segue to the navigation controller in which is A, right ?

Comment: No, you should use the protocol to invoke a method on A, which will dismiss B. Basically, B will tell A to dissmiss him, then A dismisses B, and you've got A visible back again.